# Update a column in table A with reference to the newest record in table B, in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to periodically insert new data into two tables:

Table `mstr_project`, where every time I insert one project record (1 row). I have a identity column `Project_ID`, so each time a new project record is inserted, a project ID is automatically generated.

Table `tbl_ProjectData`, where every time I insert 200 rows of new data for the new project I added to table `mstr_project`.

My question is - how do I update the `ProjectID` column in `tbl_ProjectData` every time, so that its new records take on the newly generated `Project_ID` in table `mstr_project`? This means every time, the 200 new records in table `tbl_ProjectData` will all take on the same `ProjectID` that is generated in table `mstr_project`.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Scope_Identity`:

```
DECLARE @ProjectID int;
INSERT dbo.mstr_project (Name) VALUES ('My New Project');
SET @ProjectID = Scope_Identity();

INSERT dbo.tbl_ProjectData (ProjectID, Value)
SELECT @ProjectID, Value
FROM #ProjectDataValues;
```

You can also capture the inserted value using the `OUTPUT` clause (SQL Server 2005 and up):

```
CREATE TABLE #NewProjectIDs (
   ProjectID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
);

INSERT dbo.mstr_project (Name)
OUTPUT ProjectID INTO #NewProjectIDs
SELECT 'My New Project';

INSERT dbo.tbl_ProjectData (ProjectID, Value)
SELECT N.ProjectID, V.Value
FROM
   #NewProjectIDs
   CROSS JOIN #ProjectDataValues V;
```

For the second code snippet, pay attention to how many rows you insert to your project table--if you insert multiple at once, you'll have to do something different to choose the correct project for each row that goes into the `ProjectData` table.

Note: Please stop naming your tables with "tbl_" as a prefix. You'll spare someone from murderous dreams about you some day.